# How long did a letter take from Quebec to Bordeaux in 1929?

Tags: postal-history

Just need this for authenticity for a novel I am writing . Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: On one occasion in the 1780s a letter was carried from Paris to London in less than 48 hours. But it wasn't through postal services; it was an urgent diplomatic communication.

Answer (score 2):

(I assumed this was Quebec, Canada to Bordeaux, France)

Depends on how it's traveling, but most likely a week or two.

**By sea:** [Packet ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_boat) are ships used for delivering mail, passengers, and light cargo. The Canadian Pacific Steamship Company was, despite the name, Canada's largest steamship operator in the Atlantic during the time you're looking at. Looking at some of [their 1920's ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_Ships#Inter-war_period_(1919%E2%80%931938)), such as the amazingly Canadian [SS Beaverford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Beaverford)(1928), their ships seemed to travel 15-25 knots, or roughly 37kmh/23mph. Quebec to Bordeaux [is about 5,200km](https://www.google.com/search?q=quebec%20canada%20to%20bordeaux%20france%20distance&oq=qu&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j69i60l3j69i59l2.3407j0j9&sourceid), so that trip would take about 6-7 days if going that fast. Add on a few more days for processing and land delivery, **a letter would likely take 1-2 weeks to deliver by sea.** Storms and other unfortunate events would certainly add to the time.

**By air:** [Airmail was certainly in use during this time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airmail#Scheduled_services), though I doubt it was very common for trans-Atlantic letters in 1929, since the first trans-Atlantic flights were in the mid/late 1920's. Regardless, looking at some trans-Atlantic flights such as [Charles Lindbergh's in 1927](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Lindbergh#Flight), a flight could cross the Atlantic in less than 36 hours. So, if you *really* needed a fast delivery then **airmail could delivery the letter in as little as 2-3 days**, if you could get on the list of letters that they carried in the plane.